# Xamarin forms: HTML data conversion on android and windows platforms

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, webview

**I am using a custom webview to convert my HTML data on the ios app. I am looking for the same custom renderer on android and windows.**

**MyWebView.cs**

```
public  class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Url",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**MyWebViewRenderer.cs on ios**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]

namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate();
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
        }

        public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
        {
            public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
            {
                string fontSize = "";
                if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
                {
                    fontSize = "250%";
                }
                else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
                {
                    fontSize = "375%";
                }

                string stringsss = String.Format(@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '{0}'", fontSize);
                WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) =>
                {
                    if (err != null)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(err);
                    }
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                };
                webView.EvaluateJavaScript(stringsss, handler);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Url")
            {
                Control.LoadHtmlString(Element.Url, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML and XAML.cs**

```
<local:MyWebView
  x:Name="web_view"

web_view.Url = "htmldata";
```

**Output screenshot on ios device:**

[image]

**Sample HTML data added** [**here**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TGyZbkH3B9a8nxQpr8X_cK5ZGGDmg1iL). I need the same output on android and windows platforms, so requesting custom render codes for android and windows platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present a string of HTML defined dynamically in code, you'll need to create an instance of **HtmlWebViewSource**:

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"copy the html string here";
web_view.Source = htmlSource;
```

Comment: This is working, but I have a video on the HTML data, but it's width exceeding the screen space.

Comment: Put the video in a `div` and set the padding of it .

Comment: Video is already inside the div tag, could you please have a look at the HTML data file?https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TGyZbkH3B9a8nxQpr8X_cK5ZGGDmg1iL

Comment: You could create a html file in local , and reset the size of video in it with JS . Then load the file in forms .